# Difference between having an area and having a zero area

Tags: real-analysis

My main question is. I've seen this in my textbook :

> If sets are jordan measurable (their boundaries have area zero) then the set has an area.

Okay I see that this is the definition of having area not having $0$ area.

But considered the set $$A= 0≤x≤1\   and\ 0≤y≤1 \ where \ x,y \in Q$$

Q denotes rational numbers. Boundary of this set has area $1$ which is not $0$ yet we say that this set has area $0$ not doesn't have an area

Comment: May I know why the boundary of this set has area 1?

Comment: @LeiHao Every point of the unit square is a boundary point for $D$ so that every circumscribing set has area $1$

Comment: There are different definitions of area, which agree most of the time, but disagree on edge cases. The rational numbers example you wrote is such an edge case. Your reasoning is correct that it does not have an area according to the Jordan definition, but it does have an area according to the Lebesgue measure definition. Examples like this are a major selling point of the Lebesgue measure, and one of the reasons why people generally use it more than Jordan measure.

Comment: @NickAlger I see that, why doesn't this contradict with the definition of jordan measure?

Comment: @Xenidia It does. The set you describe does not have Jordan measure.